# Why is my second site in nginx.conf not working?

Tags: nginx

I have a local NginX testing server on my Windows 10 machine. This is just for creating and testing websites, it is not served to the internet.

I've been testing one site successfully at `localhost` for a while, but now I want to add a second test site. I thought I could achieve this by duplicating the `server{}` block in the `nginx.conf` file and changing the name of the `server_name` and a few other parameters, but that it doesn't seem to work. When I try to load my second test site in Chrome, I get this error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> local_test_2’s server DNS address could not be found.

My site at `localhost` still works, though.

**Why is my second test site not working?**

Here's my current `nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type        text/html;
    sendfile            on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    server {

        #Server basics
        server_name     localhost;
        listen          80;
    index           index.html index.php;
        root            c:/nginx/html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$query_string;
        }

    location ~ .(php|htm|html)$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME c:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    }
    server {

        #Server basics
        server_name     local_test_2;
        listen          80;
        index           index.html index.php;
        root            "C:\Users\User Name\Documents\Test\example.com";

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$query_string;
        }

    location ~ .(php|htm|html)$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME c:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    }
}
```

Update:

My `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file has the following:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

The current 'localhost' specification is commented out. Should I change this file?

Comment: Because the dns cannot be resolved for `local_test_2`. Try adding it to the hosts file

Comment: @nu11p01n73R, thank you for responding. I don't have a `hosts` file that I know of. Please note this is a Windows machine, not Linux, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Every OS has a host file. You will have to map the url to the ip address. [Wiki Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Agreed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `local_test_2` in your windows host file: at

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

In host file add below line at the last

```
127.0.0.1 local_test_2
```

Also you can check reference to setup new host in nginx at: [Setting up Nginx on local machine](https://gist.github.com/netpoetica/5879685)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I updated my question with the contents of my 'hosts' file. Do I just add `127.0.0.1 local_test_2` below the commented out areas? Will this affect my first site at `localhost`?

Comment: No, you can add as much as you want. it will not affect others.

Answer (score 1):

The `local_test_2` is a url that you created for testing purpose. Since you didn't buy it from some registrar, no DNS provider will be able to resolve the url to the ip address.

Every operating system has a `hosts` file(in linux it will be `/etc/hosts`) which can be used to map the urls to ip address without the use of some online DNS service. So in your case you can append the following line,

```
127.0.0.1 local_test_2
```

which tells to route all requests to `local_test_2` to the same machine(`127.0.0.1`). No other changes are required in the hosts file.

Refer [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) for more details on hosts files and different files used in different operating systems.